# how to return to client with original extension and rename file

Tags: php, security, upload, download

i created a website with upload feature and was stored in server with .xxx extension and renamed on every files then record the original extension and file name into database.

- Client -> Upload -> images.jpg
- Server -> Saving -> md5.xxx
- Database -> Insert -> images.jpg and md5.xxx
- **Client -> Download -> images.jpg**
  (but witout rename file in server or rename to md5 again)

  how to return to client with original extension and name file with php language?

  Can you help my problem, thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a file to service the request like `downloadimage.php` and pass the file name tot it, e.g. `downloadimage.php?name=image.jpg`.
Take `$_GET['name']` and look up the file name in the data base and serve it.

Then use a rewrite to make the url pretty

```
RewriteRule /somepath/(.*) /somepath/downloadimage.php?name=$1
```

so you can access the image from `/somepath/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

aexample from PHP documentation [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

---

`downloadimage.php?name=image.jpg`

```
<?php
  // pseudo code

  $md5_filename = get_md5_filename_from_database($_GET['name']);

  // sending 

  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_GET['name'].'"');

  readfile($md5_filename);
?>
```

Now you can download by

`www.yourdomain.com/some-path/downloadimage.php?name=image.jpg`

or use `RewriteRule` in Apache configuration (as Musa said) to get

`www.yourdomain.com/some-path/image.jpg`